# Why are the demons fighting themselves as well as the protagonist?

Tags: doom-2

In Doom 2's second chapter, in a level, when I was in **Los Angeles**, there were two massive demons, one that looked like a robotic spider with a colossal brain, the other looked like a pink bulky demon who shot green laser balls at you, and they were fighting each other.

As well as some of the other demons, I thought they were trying to kill you but they were fighting themselves as well.

***Why?***

Comment: Were these boss characters or just regular enemies?

Comment: @Timmy Jim Both.

Comment: Care to add a screen shot? I think I may know exactly what you are talking about.  Also, I believe this is Doom 2.

Comment: yeah sure, but it won't be straight away though.

Comment: Yeah true, I think it was, I'm not good with titles :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nearly all enemies who accidentally hit each other when trying to hit the player will start fighting each other. The legions of hell don't all play nice together!

This is a [known feature](http://doom.wikia.com/wiki/Monster_infighting) that the player can sometimes exploit.

Comment: My thought's exactly and I was going to post this.  But also, If this is the place I think it is, I believe there is a part where a Cyber Demon is fighting a Spider Mastermind inside a shopping mall like building.  I believe this is a scripted fight if its the case, since they are always fighting one another right as they come into view of the player.  Spoiler: The Cyber Demon always seemed to win.  I also may be confusing this for Brutal Dooms version as well  but I'm unsure.

Comment: @TimmyJim - Nope. If you enter that room wrong, you have to go stand with one of them between you, to get it going (that more or less happens automatically; open door, stand still, = death). No monster is ever set with a flag to be hostile to another monster (there's no flag for it). IIRC, there is only *on alert*, *normal*, or *deaf*. There was no option for 'scripts' in doom editors from 1995. There is only, good use of placement, and those flags. The only 'script' I can think of is on ExM8s, where if you kill a Baron or higher, it ends the level. (those were the days :)

Comment: The exception is, "Barons of hell and hell knights have an immunity to each others projectiles coded onto their mobj IDs." **Retaliation infighting always was, by-design.** Without that immunity, E1M8 would be a trifle. And I'm sure a lot of work was put into making the first episode (offered as shareware in full) as attractive as possible.

Comment: So IMO, they're all supposed to retaliate against each other, but a (rather poorly construed, and hastily done ? ) script was added so that particular level didn't 'break', and that now lingers as an artifact throughout the game. One of the rooms the OP mentions in Doom2 (Cyber vs. Barons) wouldn't work w/o this either. So, it's not only something the player can exploit; level designers do it too.